# Python, find all missing fields in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, exception

I wrote a function that validates if all the fields exist in a python dictionary. Below is the code.

```
def validate_participants(self, xml_line):
    try:
       participant_type = xml_line["participants"]["participant_type"]
       participant_role = xml_line["participants"]["participant_role"]
       participant_type = xml_line["participants"]["participant_type"]
       participant_id   = xml_line["participants"]["participant_id"]
       return True
     except KeyError as err:
       log.error(f'{err}')
       return False
```

This raises an error about the missing key that it finds first and breaks execution. I want to go through the entire set of fields and raise error with all the missing fields. What's the best/efficient way to solve the problem?

Comment: Make a set containing all the required fields. Make a set containing all the actual fields. Subtract the second set from the first set, that's all the missing fields.

Comment: Check if each key exists in the dictionary first. ```if key in xml_line.keys()```

Comment: What behaviour would you want/expect if the *participants* key was absent?

Answer (score 1):

Using a `set` you can get the difference and if it is empty the keys are not missing.

```
def validate_participants(self, xml_line):
    keys = {"participant_type", "participant_role", "participant_id"}
    return keys - xml_line["participants"].keys() or True
```

The `or True` means return the set of missing keys if there are missing keys otherwise return True

**Edit:**

To answer your comment there is no need to use a try/except if you check first:

```
def validate_participants(self, xml_line):
    keys = {"participant_type", "participant_role", "participant_id"}
    missing_keys = keys - xml_line["participants"].keys()

    if missing_keys:
        #return False or
        raise Value_Error(f"Missing values: {', '.join(missing_keys)}")

    #access the values/do work or
    return True
```

Comment: Thanks! How would I wrap this in try, except? Asking for the sake of tests.

Comment: There is no need to wrap in a try except.. use the result of the difference in sets as your check before accessing the values. And you can throw an error if there are values in the difference.

Answer (score 0):

I would define a set of the expected keys and subtract the actual keys:

```
expected_keys = {...}
actual_keys = xml_line["participants"].keys()
key_diff = expected_keys - actual_keys
```

Now create a message from `key_diff` about which keys are missing.

Comment: Thanks! How would I wrap this in try, except? Asking for the sake of tests.

Comment: @user8211795 I'm not sure what `try...except` has to do with tests. You should post a new question if you are encountering new problems.